# How long would it take or is it possible to calculate permutations in python given a 6 digit number?

Tags: python, math, big-o, permutation, combinatorics

I'm attempting to compute the number of possible permutations of pixels in an hdmi display which I know to be discrete and finite, however I'm having trouble conceptualizing the big-O notation and/or processing power needed. I have the following function that works for 4 digit numbers:

```
def permutations(num):
 var = num
 for i in range(num):
  var *= 3
 return var
```

I need to apply this function to a number 2073600, however my python interpreter stops. Is there a way this can be easily done or the function adapted to use concurency?

Comment: There are 16,777,216 possible colors for each pixel.  Calculating every possible combination for over 2 million total pixels is a very very large calculation.

Comment: Update: I'm getting the impossibly low number of 8311680 on a better device. I'm sure my int has circled around at least once or the print function is having issues displaying the large number. Any way to avoid this?

Comment: You can calculate the *number* of possible permutations mathematically; no need to compute that. Since you also mention having trouble conceptualizing big-O notation, what is your goal exactly? The calculation? Just to get a feel for big-O?

Comment: The result is a number with nearly a million digits (about 8.9 * 10^989364).

Comment: I messed that up. I was looking as rbg as 3 individual constants per pixel, not on a scale of 256. I'd still like to get my original function working though.

Comment: @hobbs: A number with a million digits is more than 10^10635 times as large as that number. That may be the largest finite inaccuracy I have ever seen. 

Comment: @EricPostpischil it's a number with nearly a million digits, not "nearly a number with a million digits" :)

Comment: Evert, I'm attempting to express, in percentages, the amount of unique frames we've consumed of current hd content to show when the first exactly similar frame would occur without intention given the amount of new content created daily.

Comment: @hobbs: Hence inaccurate, not incorrect.

Comment: Eric, python 2 and 3 give the same answer. Who said they were so different ;) it's the enviroment that matters lol

Comment: At this point I'd just be happy figuring out a way to detect when my digits get too large, or a way to tell what my compilier can handle.

Comment: That sounds more like a statistics problem. Depending on the frames, there'll be a (large) bias: I would assume all frames are non-random, otherwise you'd just be displaying noise. With the abovementioned numbers, perhaps you should attempt a mathematical approach to estimate that number, instead of a direct computation.

Comment: @Evert the issue is that those factors are't nearly as important to the combinatoric problem of when all frames are repetitious. My goal is to find the point it which all frames are accounted for, maybe including a small error or deviation for the time when repetition begins and normalizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best possible solution would be to lose some accuracy and treat the number passed into the function as rounded number and then append 0's into the string to represent the actual number, or use scientific notation and a floating point. Using a floating point could have other implications under different implementations on different processors, however using a rounded integer would work any any that supported the number of digits you rounded to.